# pandas dataframe check if arrays in row are same as sample

Tags: python, pandas

I have a PD frame which looks like so (1000's of rows):

```
 pk_id   ses_id       data                                            zero_val    goal
 5410         0     [4, 6, 7, 43, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, ...        9541       1
 ...
```

where the data array has say size (64,). Now, I have another sample ND array, say `sample_array` of size (64,) and I would like to test it against all the arrays in the "data" column and return its corresponding `pk_id`. To this end I do:

```
self.pd_data.index[self.pd_data['data'] == sample_array].tolist()
```

but I keep getting:

```
pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py", line 234, in comparison_op
raise ValueError("Lengths must match to compare")
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

I dont really understand what could be wrong - I have checked the lengths and they are indeed (64,) as I expect.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare

```
series == sample_array
```

you actually unfold `self.pd_data['data']`, which is a series, and compare element wise to `sample_array`. That is

```
[x == y for x,y in zip(series, sample_array)]
```

Now, your `sample_array` has length `64` while `series` does not. Pandas doesn't like that and throws the said error.

A way to go around that is using `np.vstack`:

```
(np.vstack(self.pd_data['data'])==sample_array).all(1)
```